# How to check if you're still connected to the database with jpa

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm trying to check the database connection with jpa using the EntitityManager/Session class.

To check both cases (connected/not connected), I simply start/deactivate the service mysql before running the code.

Asking simple sql queries to the database is out of mind since it doesn't cover all cases.

I already tried:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
session.isConnected();
```

But that always returns true...

When I disable the mySQL service I want session.isConnected() to return false, but it always returns true;

Is there any other way to check for the database connection(using any other classes maybe)?

Comment: `entityManager.createQuery(Select * From ...).executeUpdate()` and you'll se fast if it's connected or not.

Comment: @Zorglube your method will very likely produce an exception, as "select" is not update )

Comment: @AlexSalauyou : `entityManager.createQuery("").getFirstResult();`

Comment: @Zorglube This will give an IllegalArgumentExcpetion

Comment: @Zorglube much worse... Anyway, such validation should be made on datasource/connection pool layer, not in business code

Comment: @AlexSalauyou : what do you purpose ?

Comment: @Mugen1994 : What do you mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: don't

Long answer: if you're developing an application where this is important, you will probably be using some sort of database connection pooling framework, like the

- [Tomcat JDBC pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html)
- [Apache Commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)
- [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)
- [C3P0 Connection pool](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0)

This will manage many important aspects for you, including connection lifecycle. In tomcat jdbc for example you can specify:

```
testOnBorrow="true"
validationQuery="select 1 from sysibm.dual"
```

This on an IBM DB2 database will test whether a connection went stale every time you use it, and also swap it out for a fresh one if the select fails. Done this way, you will never have to worry about this on the level of you application code.